# Weird artifact after enabling "Harden normals" in bevel modifier

Tags: topology, bevel

Harden normals option causing artifact to my model. It looks ok without it, but the shading is ugly so I need to use it. How to fix that artifact?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Experiment with the Width Type settings, as well as the Geometry settings

Comment: It think your problem stems from the overall topology. the hard normals are just making it show more. You have overlapping faces in the bevel. You could share a problematic chunk of your model on  https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Evripidis Lalissidis I have played around with Width Type settings before post here, but I wasn't satisfied with the results

Comment: @Robin Betts I agree, bad topology might be the answer. When I applied the bevel modifier, there were unconnected vertices. But I don't have a solution for this. I added a link to the post

Comment: 2 suggestions, that don't quite constitute an answer, because they're opinion, and depend on what you want, exactly. 1: Reduce your bevel segments to 4. (For topo reasons, it's generally better to use an even number)  2. If you want variable bevel-widths by weight, a reasonable workflow is to set all weights to 0.5, adjust mid-width bevel in the modifier, and then go round making other coherent loops tighter or looser. Switch Clamp Overlap off, and keep an eye out for overlapping generated faces.

Comment: @Robin Betts thank you. The second decision is what I have needed! Please put your comment in answer, so I can close question